# Laravel api response time are slow?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have simple app with simple query to MySQL (select from table without any join). My database records doesn't even reach 1000 record, but the time taken by laravel to get response of a simple select query is over 300-400ms. When i tried in MySQL console, it took no longer than 5ms. Is laravel really that slow? Or something was wrong with my code? Tried using eloquent, query builder, raw query all of them always took over 300ms.

My controller :

```
 public function search(Request $request){
     $origin = $request->get('origin');
     $destination = $request->get('destination');
     $o = explode(",",$origin);
     $d = explode(",",$destination);

    $response = DB::table('saved_routes')->where([
        'from_lat'=>$o[0],
        'from_lng'=>$o[1],
        'to_lat'=>$d[0],
        'to_lng'=>$d[1],      
    ])->get('value');
    
        if($response->isEmpty()){
            return response()->json([
                ['value'=>'Data not found']
            ]);
        }elseif($response[0]->value){
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

My js api call :

```
axios.get("/api/savedroutes/search?"+=${origin.lat},${origin.lng}&destination=${destination.lat},${destination.lng}`)
            .then(res => {res;})
```

PS: Im still learning Laravel.

Thanks!

Comment: Please update the code as well to the question so that members would be able to point out if you are doing something wrong in it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, MySQL has been checked without problems, the query database is not a problem but it takes time to fetch all the data that has been queried on the application => Should use pagination.

Comment: In my case the data to fetch is only one row, is it really necessary use pagination?

Comment: hi @Primery try put the following code to check 
$start = microtime(true);
// Execute the query
$time = microtime(true) - $start;

Comment: It shows 0.032534837722778. Which mean it is 30ms right? But why when i requested via api, it can took over 300ms? Im using axios perceptor to get the response time.

Comment: With results, the query fetches data with no problem. I think the root cause not in Laravel, can in js API call

Comment: Can you put logs before and after the sql query in laravel as well in JS. And see what you get. Check the network tab in your developer console of browser. compare the time range with laravel logs.

Comment: @Rafee im using axios interceptor for measuring the response time, and its constantly about 300-400ms. I tried to check query execution time using Kieu Trung method its also constantly showing 20-30ms. In browser network tab its shown :



Request sent         87 μs

Waiting (TTFB) 640.78 ms

Content Download 460.63 ms

Comment: @Primery Could you try to run the query in `tinker` if you have it or else just do `dd($response)`. Just want to see how much time does it take to respond the raw `$response.` . Should take that ~6ms for querying/parsing. And could you try other queries whats the speed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using return 1; statement after explode and then after query. Watch the API response time in all 3 scenarios, you will surely get what statement is taking time.

PS: If you want to use full potential of Laravel you should use Eloquent